# Python Restful API

Tags: python, flask

I have written a python script that will connect to the oracle database using cx_oracle and gets data and performs some action on it.

I want to expose this python script as a Restful API. In google, I read that using flask we can deploy a Python script as a Web service.

What I am not clear

1. The flask itself behaves like a server?
2. Can I deploy the python Webservice in the Web logic server?
3. I want to deploy this Webservice in production. How can I provide security to this?
4. In another site, I read using Connection, Swagger we can implement it.
5. I am actually written using flask, flask-jsonpify, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful.
6. Please suggest which packages i need to use to deploy it as WebService.

Let me know in case of any other details needed. Thanks in advance for your suggestions and guidance.

Vijay

Comment: Your question is too broad by asking it off-topic, I recommend you read [ask], [answer] and pass the [tour] if you have not done so.

Comment: According to point 5, you've already written something, so what's the problem? AFAIK, WebLogic runs Java code, not Python

Answer (score 1):

> The flask itself behaves like a server?

It can

> Can I deploy the python Webservice in the Web logic server?

Not unless you are using Jython as WebLogic runs Java applications

> I want to deploy this Webservice in production. How can I provide security to this?

See next point

> In another site, I read using Connection, Swagger we can implement it.

See next point

> I am actually written using flask, flask-jsonpify, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful.

Sounds like you've done some research into what packages you need. Maybe find more to get swagger and security figured out

> Please suggest which packages i need to use to deploy it as WebService.

Refer point 1. `flask` is all you need to run the web server